# I am using UWP winUI and im trying to dynamically switch in the content on the tabs of a tabView but failing

Tags: uwp

HI looking again for a little help ; I apologise in advance I have googled this to death, I have a tabView and when a tab is clicked I load a page the issue is that the first time I click any of the tabs the content doesn’t load, it is only when I click any of the tabs a second time that the right content loads to be clear for each tab I have a page when the tab is clicked I expect the page to load – I have set up a copy of my method for doing this  here https://pastebin.com/NDA1kwb0    Meeeow ‘may or may not be’ helped me with the original method – any help would be appreciated im going to continue to try to find a solution in the meantime; many thanks for your time

```
private void TabView_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tag = ExtractTag(sender);
            var frame = new Frame();

            switch (tag)
            {
                case "General":
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(GeneralTabView), null, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
                    break;
                case "ProsAndCons":
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(ProsAndConsTabView), null, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
                    break;
                case "ActionPoints":
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(ActionPointsTabView), null, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
                    break;
                case "MoodWall":
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(MoodWallTabView), null, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
                    break;
                case "Research":
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(ResearchTabView), null, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
                    break;
                case "Notes":
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(NotesTabView), null, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
                    break;
                case "Export":
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(ExportTabView),null, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
                    break;
            }

            var target = ExtractTabItem(sender);
            target.Content = frame;


        }

        private static TabViewItem ExtractTabItem(object sender)
        {
            var temp = (TabView) sender;
            var target = (TabViewItem) temp.SelectedItem;
            return target;
        }

        private static string ExtractTag(object sender)
        {
            var temp = (TabView) sender;
            var target = (TabViewItem) temp.SelectedItem;
            var tag = target.Tag;
            return (string)tag;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a tabView and when a tab is clicked I load a page the issue is that the first time I click any of the tabs the content doesn’t load, it is only when I click any of the tabs a second time that the right content.

Great question, this behavior is very strange, please feel free post it in WinUI github issue box. In general, we often initial `TabViewItem` in `TabView` Loaded event. So our **workaround** is set the `TabViewItem.Content` as Frame in Loaded event, and `Navigate` in 
`OnSelectionChanged` event.

```
private void MyTabView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        (sender as TabView).TabItems.Add(CreateNewTab(i));
    }

}
private TabViewItem CreateNewTab(int index)
{
    TabViewItem newItem = new TabViewItem();
    newItem.Header = $"Document {index}";
    newItem.IconSource = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SymbolIconSource() { Symbol = Symbol.Document };
    newItem.Tag = $"Document{index}";    
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    newItem.Content = frame;
    return newItem;
}

private void MyTabView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tag = ExtractTag(sender);
    var target = ExtractTabItem(sender);
    var frame = target.Content as Frame;

    switch (tag)
    {
        case "Document1":
            frame.Navigate(typeof(TestPAge));
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I did preloaded the tads in the enf

Answer (score 1):

+1, this could be a bug. Please feel free to file an issue on the WinUI GitHub repo here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/new/choose

Another resource is the Xaml Controls Gallery, which has a bunch of TabView samples. You can download the app from the Store at https://aka.ms/xamlgalleryapp, or visit the GitHub repo at https://aka.ms/xamlgallerysource

I don't think there is enough information here to totally debug the issue. For more help, please include the markup to define the TabView and any relevant methods for first launch (such as the OnLoaded event, constructors, etc.)